# How do I get Firefox to use Bing as the default search provider?

Tags: firefox, bing

How can I get Firefox to use Bing as it's default search provider, and use it on the context menu for searching the selected text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go here and [install the Bing plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addons/policy/0/10434/45541).
2. Once you install the plugin Live Search will show up in your dropdown options in your Firefox searchbox.
3. Click that and you’re all set.

([source](http://jamespoling.com/how-to-make-bing-your-default-search-engine-in-firefox-and-chrome/))

Comment: Shame it doesn't show up when you click through the links from in-browser to add providers...